# Kivymd: How to change a ‘MDTextfield’ into an ‘int’

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I’m using Kivymd since two weeks ago and I’m wondering if there is the possibility to change the input from a ‘MDTextfield‘ into an ‘int’.

I’m asking this because I want that the input is between the value of 0 and 95.

Is it possible to do so or is there another way to get a numerical input from the user between 0 and 95?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must correctly set the `input_filter`, like this:

```
MDTextField:
    input_filter: "int"
```

Comment: And you would then use the built-in `int()` to convert the text from that `MDTextField` into an actual integer.

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.